# Changing row item typeface in a ListView on runtime

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I created a `ListView` with a custom array adapter of `MyObject`. One instance of `MyObject` contains a `String` and a `boolean`. When I visualize the `ListView` all my items appear in bold and if you tap on one of those items you start a new `Activity`. What that I want to do is that every time that you press back and come back to that `ListView`, you visualize the item that you clicked not bold. This is my custom `ArrayAdapter`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyObject> {
private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<MyObject> values;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyObject> values) {
    super(context, R.layout.my_item, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_item, parent, false);
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
    textView.setText(values.get(position).getMyObjectName());
    if(values.get(position).isSetted()){
        textView.setTypeface(null, 0);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

}

In my `Activity` I put:

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and the code actually works, But there is a problem: after you tapped some items, other untapped items become not bold when you come back! This happens in a random way! Why is this happening?

```
    @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    String item = objList.get(position).getMyObjectName();
    objList.get(position).setSetted(true);


    to_ans.putExtra("ItemName", item);
    startActivity(to_ans);

}
```

The `boolean` value of the items initially are all set at `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to revert to the default **bold** style if `isSetted()` is `false`(to revert to the default style a potential recycled `View`(for  the case when `convertView` is not `null`) who may be set without bold):

```
if(values.get(position).isSetted()){
    textView.setTypeface(null);
} else {
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.BOLD);
}
```